# How to modify order by clause using DataPageRequest

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want to retrieve a list of records which should be order by email id with the customized way i.e.

```
Select * from Table t order by UPPER(t.email);
```

So, while creating DataPageRequest Object, I am passing the values as :

```
DataPageRequest pageRequest = new DataPageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize, UPPER("email"));
```

But it is showing errors.

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by using ignoreCase() method available in spring-data-jpa(supported by version 1.9.0 onwards).